# Json encode a complex dict

Tags: python, python-2.x

How would I json encode the following dict:

```
data = {
    'name': 'david',
    'avatar': open('file.jpg').read()
}
```

When I try doing `json.dumps(data)` I get a `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Comment: Do `unicode(open('file.jpg').read())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you try to encode a picture in json. If you want to display it on a web page, consider using a data-url-encoding:

```
image = "data:image/jpg;base64,%s" % ''.join(open('file.jpg').read().encode('base64').split())
data = {
    'name': 'david',
    'avatar': image,
}
json_data = json.dumps(data)
```

or if you only need the binary data, simply use:

```
image = open('file.jpg').read().encode('base64')
data = {
    'name': 'david',
    'avatar': image,
}
json_data = json.dumps(data)

#decode
data = json.loads(json_data)
image = data['avatar'].decode('base64')
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for that. It works in terms of encoding. How would I then decode that data back into the exact file data, `open('file.jpg').read()`?

Comment: This helped a lot, but instead of using `open` I used `StringIO`(I am fetching image from database)

Answer (score 2):

You must be using Python 2.x.  Since you have Unicode data in the string, you need to make it a [Unicode string literal](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

```
>>> import json
>>> data = {
...     'name': 'david',
...     'avatar': u'\xed\xb3\x1cW\x7f\x87\x1c\xb9*Pw\x9a#W\x05\xeaNs\xe4\xaa@\xddi\x8e\\\x15\xa8;\xcd\x91\xab\x02u\xa79rU\xa0\xee4\xf7K\xb9\x05{t\x02\xc6I\xb6\xaa\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82...'
... }
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"name": "david", "avatar": "\\u00ed\\u00b3\\u001cW\\u007f\\u0087\\u001c\\u00b9*Pw\\u009a#W\\u0005\\u00eaNs\\u00e4\\u00aa@\\u00ddi\\u008e\\\\\\u0015\\u00a8;\\u00cd\\u0091\\u00ab\\u0002u\\u00a79rU\\u00a0\\u00ee4\\u00f7K\\u00b9\\u0005{t\\u0002\\u00c6I\\u00b6\\u00aa\\u00bf\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000IEND\\u00aeB`\\u0082..."}'
>>>
```

By placing `u` before the string literal, you tell Python to treat the string as Unicode.

Note that this is unnecessary in Python 3.x since [all strings are now Unicode by default](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit).

Comment: Could you please take a look at the updated question? I don't have that much control over the string (I don't think).

Comment: It's in general a bad idea, to interpret binary data as unicode.

Comment: @Daniel -- ok, then how would I pass the binary data as binary data in the json?